# How to make this simple C# code more efficent/elegant

Tags: c#

I've three three textBox, `textBoxLectura1`, `textBoxLectura2` and `textBoxLectura3`. When someone clicks on the button `button3` I want just to print the entries the user has written.

I made this code and works perfect. I would like to know if there's a more elegant/efficent way to do it without using so many `if` statements. I would like to maintain the `arrayList` structure.

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ArrayList myarray2 = new ArrayList();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxLectura1.Text) == false)
        {
            myarray2.Add(textBoxLectura1.Text);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxLectura2.Text) == false)
        {
            myarray2.Add(textBoxLectura2.Text);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxLectura3.Text) == false)
        {
            myarray2.Add(textBoxLectura3.Text);
        }

        if (myarray2.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string values in myarray2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(values );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("no entrys");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxLectura1.Text)) instead of if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxLectura1.Text) == false).

Comment: First thing - dont use == false ... use ! operator like this: (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxLectura3.Text)

Comment: Why the downvote if im just asking for an improvement for a code I did?

Comment: @Borja: Code review is often off-topic. There is a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site that would usually be a better home. (note: I wasn't the downvoter).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MattBurland . I didn't knew there was a `code review` site. I will use that next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way might be to do something like:

```
var strings = new List<string>() 
{
    textBoxLectura1.Text,
    textBoxLectura2.Text,
    textBoxLectura3.Text
};

var output = string.Join('\n',strings.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(output)) 
{
    Console.Writeline(output);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("no entrys");
}
```

A couple of points here. Don't use `ArrayList`. A typed `List<T>` is better in pretty much every way. `ArrayList` is a hold over from C# when it didn't have generics. The only reason to ever use `ArrayList` is if you are dealing with some legacy (pre 2.0) code that needs it. A `List<object>` is functional equivalent to an `ArrayList`, but since a lot of the time you are dealing with homogeneous collections it's much easier to use a `List<T>`, where `T` is whatever type you are populating your collection with (in this case `string`), and not have to deal with casting every time you try and get something from your collection.

What we do in the code here is we create a `List<string>` and immediately initialize it with the values of all our textboxes `.Text` property. It doesn't matter if they are null or empty at the point.

Then we use the really helpful `string.Join` method. This takes a collection of strings and glues them together with a separator. In this case, we use the newline character (`\n`). But, since we don't want to include nulls or empty strings (`String.Join` would otherwise insert extra newline characters), we use a simple LINQ `.Where` statement to select only those strings that aren't null or empty.

Comment: This looks great, but as I said on the post, I would like to work with `arrayList`.

Comment: @Borja Why `ArrayList`? It shouldn't be used anymore. `List<T>` supersedes it and it is type safe.

Comment: There's no valid reason to use ArrayList since .net 1.1.

Comment: As I'm new in `c#` (started two weeks ago) and I did a lot of use of `ArrayList` in Java which are the data structures that I feel more confortable with. But I will try the `List<String>`. Thanks.

Comment: @Borja: The *only* reason to ever use `ArrayList` is if you are dealing with some legacy (pre 2.0) code that needs it. A `List<object>` is functional equivalent to an `ArrayList`, but since a lot of the time you are dealing with homogeneous collections it's much easier to use a `List<T>`, where `T` is whatever type you are populating your collection with, and not have to deal with casting every time you try and get something from your collection

Comment: @MattBurland Just one little thing. I'm getting a sintax error on the `var strings = new List<string> `. When you declare the `textBoxLectura1.Text;` do you have to put a `;` or a `,` ?

Comment: @Borja: Whoops. That was my fault. Those should be commas.

Comment: @MattBurland Argh, I'm still getting an error. It seems you have to put an `;` at the end of somewhere. I tried but putting at the last one, `textBoxLectura3.Text;` but still doesnt work. Also after the `}` but error again. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Borja: Sorry, coffee hadn't quite kicked in yet. It should be right now.

Comment: @MattBurland That line works fine now, thanks. But now I'm having problems with the `string.Join('\n',strings.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));` . The error that the compiler shows is that you cant convert from `char` to `string` . And also another one that you can't convert from  `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'` to `'string[]'`. Any ideas? Thanks again, Matt.

Comment: Nevermind. I did it, thanks for everything @MattBurland

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take on it.

```
var notEmpty = new[]  { textBoxLectura1.Text, textBoxLectura2.Text, textBoxLectura3.Text}
    .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
    .ToArray();

if (!notEmpty.Any())
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Entries");
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, notEmpty));
```

I also agree with other posters, `ArrayList` vs an `IEnumerable<T>` implementing container is a no-brainer, you should be using a strongly-typed collection type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to Check & Add:.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ArrayList myarray2 = new ArrayList();

            ChecknAdd(textBoxLectura1, myarray2);
            ChecknAdd(textBoxLectura2, myarray2);
            ChecknAdd(textBoxLectura3, myarray2);

            if (myarray2.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string values in myarray2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(values);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no entrys");
            }

        }

        void ChecknAdd(TextBox txt, System.Collections.ArrayList Ary)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text) == false)
            {
                Ary.Add(txt.Text);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

create a procedure like this:

```
private void addOnArray(ArrayList array, String text) {

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) == false)
    {
        array.Add(text);
    }

}
```

And in the caller:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ArrayList myarray2 = new ArrayList();
    addOnArray(myarray2, textBoxLectura1.Text);
    addOnArray(myarray2, textBoxLectura2.Text);
    addOnArray(myarray2, textBoxLectura3.Text);

    if (myarray2.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string values in myarray2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(values );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("no entrys");
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your if(s) to ternary operators...  When you add to a List, it'll return the index it was added to, otherwise just assign a -1 to the receiving variable

Then use the same ternary logic to know if you want to print the contents of your ArrayList, or just print "No Entries"

```
        ArrayList myarray2 = new ArrayList();

        int index = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxLectura1.Text) ? myarray2.Add(textBoxLectura1.Text) : -1;
        index = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxLectura2.Text) ? myarray2.Add(textBoxLectura2.Text) : -1;
        index = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxLectura3.Text) ? myarray2.Add(textBoxLectura3.Text) : -1;

        Console.WriteLine(myarray2.Count > 0 ? string.Join("\n", myarray2.ToArray()) : "No Entries");
```

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate the approaches in other answers and the way couple of them have explained why to use Generics vs ArrayLists. This is how I perform it (*learnt it thanks to **SO***):

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxCollection = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();

        foreach (TextBox box in textBoxCollection)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(box.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(box.Text);   
            }
        }
```